# How to delete a Tip in a lottery program with a button?

Tags: java, javafx

I am programming a lottery program in JavaFX (6 numbers of a 6x7 field + 1 lucky number) which allows the user to create max 10 tips at once. Then the program evaluates if he won.
My current problem is to delete a Tip that has been added. I have a Class "Tip" which consists of an HBox with 7 labels inside (for the 7 chosen numbers) and a button to delete this Tip (so every Tip has its own delete button).

My function to add a Tip works (even though, I don't really know if this is really clean. So if you see any improvements, I'd be really thankful! :-)).

Under the following link, you can find my entire code:

https://github.com/Lucindor/Lottery.git

**The main issue or part that I'm stuck is in the Controller from line 73 to 80 (deleteTip method).**

My main idea was to removethe parent of the button (which should be the Tip(?)), which should have removed the entire tip...but this didn't work. I couldn't get any ideas more.

In the end, **I want to be able to click on any delete button which removes this tip and moves all the tips below (So that it's like a list).**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please include your code here in your question, instead of a link

Comment: You may find it helpful to preapre a [mcve] in which the model has an `ObservableList<Tip>`; `remove()` will cause a listening `ListView` or `TableView` to update itself in response.